# Windows 8 Storage Spaces WMI error

Tags: wmi, windows-8

I have a question regarding WMI and Storage Spaces.

Setup:
I have created a Storage Pool that contains a virtual disk that in turn contains 3 physical disks. I am using parity, which requires me to have a minimum of three disks to create the virtual disk. I am using C# on a Windows 8 machine using VS 2012.

Problem:
I plug a fourth disk into the machine and try to add it to the virtual disk using WMI. The AddPhysicalDisk method returns a **'cache out of date (40003)'** error. I am querying and retrieving an instance of the MSFT_VirtualDisk only after I receive the event and this is the first operation I am performing on it. Could someone tell me why this error is occurring?

Other data:
I have tried to use the same physical disk to expand the pool instead of the Virtual Disk and this works fine. The problem with that approach is that I can't expand the virtual disk to take that additional disk into the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that you could try:

- Have you added this 4th physical disk to the storage pool using the "AddPhysicalDisk" method? If not, you *must* add it to the pool. This is how Storage Spaces knows that it is OK to use the disk.
- Did you create the VirtualDisk using the "PhysicalDisksToUse" parameter? If yes, you still need to add it to the pool first. Once in the pool, then try using AddPhysicalDisk on the virtual disk.

Note that PhysicalDisksToUse is a way to further restrict allocations within a pool. If you want your virtual disk to automatically use all available storage, omit this parameter when creating the virtual disk.

Judging by the error code (which can sometimes be treated as "not found"), you have probably not added the physical disk to the pool first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did try to add the disk to the storage pool first, but that resulted in the AddPhysicalDisk returning "Invalid Parameter(5)". I have tried it with the same disk reference that I used to add the disk to the storage pool as well as a completely new one by querying MSFT_PhysicalDisk. I have not created the VirtualDisk using PhysicalDisksToUse, I needed the Virtual disk to occupy the entire storage in the pool, so I let it use the maximum space available. Do I need to use PhysicalDisksToUse? The fact that I am using mirroring and fixed size might also play a part.

Comment: Which call to AddPhysicalDisk failed with Invalid Parameter? StoragePool? or VirtualDisk? If it was the VirtualDisk call, this is expected if you did not use PhysicalDisksToUse when creating the disk. If you do not have a specific reason to finely control allocation of the virtual disk, then I would ignore the PhysicalDisksToUse parameter as well as the Add/RemovePhysicalDisk methods on the VirtualDisk class.

Comment: I realized that the error was because I was not adding the Physical disks initially and was able to fix it. The reason I am trying to add specific disks is for this reason. If I create a virtual disk with two 1TB HDDs with mirroring from scratch I get a drive that is 1TB in size. If I use 3 from scratch, I get a drive 1.5T in size. If I create a virtual disk that has two disks to begin with and then try to add a third one, I am not able to expand the disk from 1 TB to 1.5. The only time it will expand is to 2TB after I add the 4th disk. Thick provisioning is preventing expansion maybe?

Answer (score 1):

"with two 1TB HDDs with mirroring "

Here's the catch, you're creating a mirrored **vDisk**.
When creating a mirror SSP will stripe across all physical disks using a stripe set with n columns. The reason "n columns" is important is that if you want to add more disks to the set, you need to match the number of columns to do it.
Check the number of columns by looking at the properties of the vDisk. Then use this little formula:

"minimum no of disks to extend the set" = n columns * n data copies

So if you create a mirror with 2 disks you will end up with 1 column and 2 data copies, hence to extend this set you need to provide 1*2=2 disks. That's why you cannot extend it to 1.5TB when adding a 3rd disk, you need to add 2 new disks to extend it.